# Foreach on value blade Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel when I try to display my data via my view...
Here is my code to browse everything with my view :

```
    @foreach($recipes as $t=>$d)
    {{$t}} // doesn't display all the key
    @endforeach
    
    {{$recipes->LABEL}} // work great
```

Their is the result : incrementing preventsLazyLoading exists wasRecentlyCreated timestamps

Their is my controller and the model :

```
Model : 
 /**
     * Get a recipe from its primary id : recipe_id
     * If fail it return 404 exception
     * Else return the collection with all the data of a recipe
     *
     * @param integer $id id of the recipe in the db
     * @return Collection the collection that have been finded by his id
     */
    public static function getRecipe($id)
    {
        return self::findOrFail($id);
    }

Controller : 

function getRecipe($id)
    {
        return view('recipe_detail')->with('recipes', Recipe::getRecipe($id));
    }
```

Is their any solution to display with foreach and with call the key ?

Thanks

Comment: You are using findOrFail which gives only one data.. How are you using foreach in your blade?

Comment: you are iterating a single model instance not a Collection ... when you iterate an object like that it will be iterating its public properties, which you don't want to do .... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I’m only trying to iterate on the find id. Just to display all the column funded in the return row but when I iterate on it, it only display some strange attribut

Comment: that isn't how you get the "attributes" ... if you iterate an object like this it will only iterate the public properties ... attributes are not properties

Answer (score 0):

You have a single object `$recipe` that you are trying to loop on in your blade file.

This method:

```
 public static function getRecipe($id)
 {
     return self::findOrFail($id);
 }
```

returns the single object based on the `$id`.  If you want a **collection**, skip the `$id` and use `get()` or `all()`, something like:

```
public function getRecipes(){
  return self::all()
}
```

Or, just call it right in the controller without need for the method in the Model: `$recipes = Recipe::all();`

You can then loop on `$recipes` in the blade file because it is now a collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the "attributes" of the Model then you have to ask the Model for them; you can use the `getAttributes` method:

```
@foreach ($model->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
    ...
@endforeach
```